# [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL (10060) and SSIS

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, ssis

This a weird issue.  I have two machines running the exact same code base.  One can connect, the other cannot connect via SSIS, yet both can connect via the commandline.

The mySQL was set to use % for connection.  No restrictions.

From SSIS I get this error:

```
[ODBC Error] Error:

ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (10060)
ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (10060)
   at ST_54325c21a3fe4578ace6a2d1834e2275.ScriptMain.GetDataSet(String query)
   at ST_54325c21a3fe4578ace6a2d1834e2275.ScriptMain.Main()
```

Using the exact same connection string in a C# app with the exact same code:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=XXXX;User=XXXX;Password=XXXX;Option=3;
```

It works fine.

and on another server the code runs fine on SSIS.

Any ideas?  I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you found a solution (after 3 years haha)?

Comment: I moved to open source ahahahahah